# Retrive Data from specific year interval in djnago

Tags: python, django, postgresql

How are you? I need some help please. I am working in Django and I need to make a query that should return a value in specific year interval. for example if year interval is 2 than it should return data for 10 years, if apply date was 2020 than it should return data in 2020, 2022, 2024 like that and if the apply date was 2023 and interval was 3, than it also should return data similarly.
The Code is below, i have tried:

```
diff = get_factors_of(i.year_num)
componant3 = ComponentInfo.objects.filter(component__category__water_scheme = scheme,maintenance_interval__in = diff_year, apply_date__lte = i.end_date, interval_unit='Year').aggregate(labour_cost = Sum(F('labour_cost')*F('component_numbers'),output_field=FloatField()),\
                    material_cost = Sum(F('material_cost')*F('component_numbers'),output_field=FloatField()), \
                    replacement_cost = Sum(F('replacement_cost')*F('component_numbers'),output_field=FloatField()),\
                    maintenance_cost = Sum(F('maintenance_cost')*F('component_numbers'),output_field=FloatField()),)
```

and the diff return method is :

```
def get_factors_of(num):
    """Return factor of integer number"""
    factor_list = [1]
    for i in range(1, num + 1):
        if num == 1:
            factor_list = [x for x in range(1,15)]
        elif num % i == 1:
            factor_list.append(i)
    return factor_list
```

this method should return a specific interval range

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your problem, you need to provide more variables to the function. You need 1. starting year, 2. interval, 3. end year. Otherwise it cannot be properly counted for any circumstances.

```
def get_years(starting_year, interval, end_year):
    yield starting_year  # this depends if you want starting list or not
    for year in range(starting_year, end_year + 1, interval):  # +1 means that end_year may be included
        yield year
```

It's possible to also use `list` and `return`, but `yield` is perfect for that job. If `range` is enough, then it can be even shorter:

```
def get_years(starting_year, interval, end_year):
    return range(starting_year, end_year + 1, interval)
```

Third integer in `range` function is basically what you need - what step size should `range` function process.

Comment: thank you so much, i need function to return list of interval number , if periods is 10 years and interval is 2 than i need number 2 in every 2 years interval.

Comment: This is what that code is going to do. If you have: `starting_year=2020`, `end_year=2030` and `interval=2` it will give you: `2020, 2022, 2024, 2026, 2028, 2030`.